# Is there a need to include all tests in the testing part in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to RoR and in the basic demo application i am using **rspec** test only and it serves the purpose, but are the tests like **autotest**, spork etc also required?

Comment: are you asking if it's required to put everything in test/ or if it's required to use all those tests?

Comment: i mean if it's required to use all those tests!!

Comment: tests are optional. you don't even need to use rspec to make something work. they're there to ensure a more robust code. here's a link that may be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/126801/334545

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autotest is a tool that makes your tests run on the background everytime you change them. So, if you change a test and save the file, the test is automatically run in your shell. It's very handy when programming.

Spork is mainly a way to make your tests run a lot faster.  Both autotest and spork are tools, they are not tests. And you may use them or not.

For instance, i prefer watchr over autorun (they do the same thing) and i don't really use spork(because i don't want another open shell in visor :P)